# MvvmCross Wpf Exception Handling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to Wpf using MvvmCross. I have been using MvvmCross for WindowsPhone App for a while now and exception handling isn't that hard because I can use the default App.xaml.cs and its `UnhandledException` event. However, in a WPF project, the App.xaml.cs file is empty so whenever one of my ViewModels encounters an exception, it crashes because I don't know where to handle exceptions.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use UnhandledException in a similar manner to your Windows Phone App.

As explained by Stuart for WPF [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/566635/MvvmCross-TipCalc-Step-Creating-a-WPF-UI), under "Modify the App.xaml.cs to Use Setup", you should have a DoSetup method in App.xaml.cs.

You can then add event handlers something like this:

```
DispatcherUnhandledException += OnDispatcherUnhandledException;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;
```